# How to filter fields in one2many base on it's many2one?

Tags: python-2.7, default, default-value, openerp-7

We know that the class *sale_order* has *sale_order_line*. I am wondering now how can I filter/set default value for some fields.

Here is my illustration.

In class *res_partner,* I add a field of type selection:

```
'part_type' : fields.selection([('child','Child'),('adult','Adult'),('senior','Senior')],'Partner Type')
```

In *sale_order_line,* I also add this:

```
'rule_applied' : fields.selection([('low','Low'),('lower','Lower'),('lowest','Lowest')],'Rule')
```

Now, if a user selects a partner in *sale_order* and if he tries to add an item on its *sale_order_line*, I want to set the default value of *rule_applied* according to this criteria:

> If the partner_type of the selected partner is a child then the default value of the rule_applied is Lowest, if senior then Lower and if adult then Low.

I tried this method but it does not work:

```
def default_get(self, cr, uid, fields, context=None):
    res = super(sale_order_line, self).default_get(cr, uid, fields, context=context)
    _logger.info("\n\n\t\t\tSetting up rule >>> fields %s"%(str(context)))
    _logger.info("\n\n\t\t\tSetting up rule >>> res %s"%(str(res)))
    if 'order_partner_id' in fields:
        partner_id = res['order_partner_id']
        order_id = res['order_id']
        if order_partner_id:
            part_list = self.pool.get('res.partner').search(cr,uid,[('customer','=',True)])
            partner = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr,uid,part_list,context=context)
            if partner.part_type == 'child':
                res['rule_applied'] = 'lowest'
            elif partner.part_type == 'adult':
                res['rule_applied'] = 'low'
            elif partner.part_type == 'senior':
                res['rule_applied'] = 'lowe'                
            else:
                res['rule_applied'] = False
        if order_id:
            order = self.pool.get('sale.order').browse(cr,uid,order_id,context=context)
            partner = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr,uid,order.partner_id.id,context=context)
            if partner.part_type == 'child':
                res['rule_applied'] = 'lowest'
            elif partner.part_type == 'adult':
                res['rule_applied'] = 'low'
            elif partner.part_type == 'senior':
                res['rule_applied'] = 'lowe'                
            else:
                res['rule_applied'] = False

    return res
```

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: if you solved your error with given answer, than I may advice to accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

*default_get* returns a dictionary of the default values for fields(set on the object class, by the user preferences, or via the context).

So we need to update that dictionary with our desire value using *.update({'field_name': value}) method*.

Try with this code:

```
def default_get(self, cr, uid, fields, context=None):
    res = super(sale_order_line, self).default_get(cr, uid, fields, context=context)
    _logger.info("\n\n\t\t\tSetting up rule >>> fields %s"%(str(context)))
    _logger.info("\n\n\t\t\tSetting up rule >>> res %s"%(str(res)))
    if 'order_partner_id' in fields:
        partner_id = res['order_partner_id']
        order_id = res['order_id']
        if order_partner_id:
            part_list = self.pool.get('res.partner').search(cr,uid,[('customer','=',True)])
            partner = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr,uid,part_list,context=context)
            if partner.part_type == 'child':
                res.update({'rule_applied': 'lowest'})
            elif partner.part_type == 'adult':
                res.update({'rule_applied': 'low'})
            elif partner.part_type == 'senior':
                res.update({'rule_applied': 'lowe'})              
            else:
                res.update({'rule_applied': False})
        if order_id:
            order = self.pool.get('sale.order').browse(cr,uid,order_id,context=context)
            partner = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(cr,uid,order.partner_id.id,context=context)
            if partner.part_type == 'child':
                res.update({'rule_applied': 'lowest'})
            elif partner.part_type == 'adult':
                res.update({'rule_applied': 'low'})
            elif partner.part_type == 'senior':
                res.update({'rule_applied': 'lowe'})           
            else:
                res.update({'rule_applied': False})

    return res
```